# how to make small binaries using assembly?

Tags: assembly, linker, ld, elf, binutils

I was writing some assembly code for some project of mine and I saw something interesting. the size of binary when linked is so big. so I tested and tested and even with smallest possible lines of code, output Elf binary is so large. for example:

```
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
    movl $1,%eax
    movl $0,%ebx
    int $0x80
```

after assembling and linking above code the result binary is **more than 4kb**!
the funny thing is, most of the binary is filled with zeroes.
I tried so many things to find out what is the cause to no success. 
can someone please explain to me what is the problem here?

I simply assemble and link the file:

```sh
as -o <OBJ_NAME> <SOURCE NAME>
ld -o <ELF_NAME> <OBJ_NAME>
```

recommending any form of resource for further reading will be nice.

as you may guessed, I use 64bit GNU/Linux

thanks.

Comment: Between "too broad" and off-topic for requesting off-site resources, I choose "too broad".  But try googling "elf size linux".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I find the question quite specific. There are clear instructions on how to reproduce and the unexpected result the OP does not understand (about 4 KB of zeroes in the executable). Not sure what off-site resources you are referring to either.

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin, "recommending any form of resource for further reading will be nice."  As for breadth, yes, the question presents a specific example, but that does not in itself make the question a specific one, especially if you take the question to be the one in the title.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, I missed the part about recommendation when I read the qustion; my bad.  I agree that the title could use some improvement, it does sound very broad.

Comment: If you're making x86-64 code, I'd suggest using 64-bit `syscall` to make an exit system call, not the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with alignment. See `readelf -eW <ELF_NAME>`. The interesting bit is

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000401000 001000 00000c 00  AX  0   0  1
```

Note the `Off` column. This is the offset in the file, and the `.text` section starts with `0x1000`, which is 4K.

Same picture if you look at the *program headers*. The space that is filled with zeroes is between the end of the ELF header and 0x1000.

Why is this?

First, because the ELF standard dictates that

> Loadable process segments must have congruent values for p_vaddr and p_offset, modulo the page size.

(see `man elf`). The page size on your system (mine as well) is 4K. This is the value that you see in `p_align`.

Second, the virtual address the linker has assigned to the start of the "text" segment — same as for the `.text` section here, because that's all that segment contains here — is `0x0000000000401000`. Therefore the hexadecimal representation of the "text" segment's offset in the file has to end with `000`. But 0 is already taken by the readonly segment containing the ELF header (the very beginning of the file). The second choice is `0x1000`.

Why did the linker choose 0x401000 as the virtual address for the text section? I don't know. I think, if you tweak the linker script a little, you'll be able to have a smaller resluting executable.

---

As Peter and that other guy have pointed out, page-size alignment can be disabled using the `-n` linker option:

```
'-n'
'--nmagic'
    Turn off page alignment of sections, and disable linking against
    shared libraries[…]
```

That way I get

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000400078 000078 00000c 00  AX  0   0  1

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000078 0x0000000000400078 0x0000000000400078 0x00000c 0x00000c R E 0x1
```

and the size of the executable is down to 664 bytes (344 after `strip`ping).

---

With GNU ld, you can use *linker scripts* to fine-control the layout of linker output files. `ld.bfd` (usually also known as just `ld`) interprets a default linker script if the user doesn't specify one. It can be obtained with `ld --verbose`. You can then edit it and supply your version instead of the default with `-T <your-script>`.

I edited out the first occurance of

```
. = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
```

(before `.text`) and got 720 (400 when `strip`ped) bytes. This is different from the result of using the `-n` option. You still get 2 loadable segmemts, and their `p_align` is still `0x1000`.

There are efficiency implications for having `p_align` < `MAX_PAGE_SIZE` that I don't fully understand. (Pages won't be loaded as fast due to harder address computation? I think there should be a better explanation.) Feel free to edit the answer, if you know more about this or where it's explained.

Comment: I think you want `ld --nmagic` to turn off page-alignment of sections, like the other answer is doing accidentally.

Comment: +1 Since this is the correct analysis while I was way off, feel free to copy the useful parts from my answer and let's see if OP or a mod will flip the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! I incorporated the `-n` approach into my answer and also described another one using a custom linker script.